# Origins and meaning of "can you not"

Tags: expressions, hiberno-english

What is the origin and meaning of the phrase *can you not*? To my ear, it has an archaic tone, but searches yield entries in the urban dictionary, along with one quote from *Sense and Sensibility*. Its twisted syntax, potential ambiguity, and indirectness intrigue me. Part of my language heritage is from Irish American, so I also wonder if this hints at its source.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why OP should think we need to find an 'origin' for such a standard construction.

Increasingly, people avoid using a negating **not** at the end of a sentence, as shown by [this NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=will%20you%20not,are%20we%20not,has%20he%20not&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), but I wouldn't go so far as to call the usage 'archaic'. A little 'dated', or 'formal', perhaps, since the modern style is generally more informal. People are more likely to say/write "**Can't you**" today, but it really is just a matter of style.

[image]

Comment: Amusingly, I added "can't you" and "can not you" to your nGram link. "Can't you" peaks higher than all the samples you listed, but the non-contracted form "can not you" is flatlined at or near zero

Comment: @horatio I suggest you try *cannot* rather than *can not*.

Comment: of course, you are correct. that is lower than `has he not` (the green line)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to FumbleFingers' answer, there's the more sarcastic meaning of "can you not": that is, "please don't", as in, "Can you not play the piano so loud in the middle of the night?".  In fact, this is how I parsed your question until I read the other answer (needless to say, I was surprised to apparently learn that *Sense and Sensibility* had such a hip style).  I don't know how this version came to be, except through the usual method of sarcastically twisting a very weak statement, literally meaning "Do you potentially have the capability not to...", into a strong one.

Comment: I hardly think there's anything unusual going on there. It's quite common to use slightly archaic/formal phrasing when being sarcastic. As an example, I kinda think *"I hardly think"* qualifies on that score! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: What's your point?  I didn't say it was unusual.

Comment: Well, my point *was* that it's hardly much of an "answer" to highlight the fact that "Can you not do that?" might be a sarcastic/rhetorical question. But you're getting upvotes for it, so good luck to you! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The sarcastic meaning is different from a twisting of the usual meaning.  You can't, for example, say "Can't you do that?" and mean the same as saying "can you not do that" sarcastically.  You could, of course, say "Can't you do that?" sarcastically to mock someone for *not* being able to "do that", but that is not the same as what I described at all.  The OP seems to be curious about "potential ambiguity", and my "answer" identifies one such.

Comment: Hmm. I think the primary nuance of "Can you not *do* that?" as a rhetorical question actually comes from the fact that it's a dated/formal construction, conveying superiority/condescension (even more so with "could" instead of "can", perhaps). My gut feeling is that dated/formal phrasing is a common device for put-downs. As in "Mind your manners, young lady!" as said to a recalcitrant daughter, for example. So I don't think it's peculiar to OP's particular phrase. But like I say, you've got the upvotes, so you must be on to something.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentary Terms And Conditions May Apply, Mark Zuckerberg asks the documenters if they are recording him, they say yes, and mark replies with "Could you not?". I believe the use of this word is ironically a subtle protest against personal information being given to big-brother and sold to marketers by internet bohemeths such as Facebook.